# About alternating series with some conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Statement : The alternating series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} u_n $ , $u_n\gt 0 $ will not be convergent if either $u_{n+1} \not\lt u_n $ $\forall n$ or $\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n \neq 0 $

Is this statement right?
Is there no alternating series ( with non monotonic terms $\{u_n\}$) which is convergent?

I thought about $u_n =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n^2},  & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\
\frac{1}{2^n}, & \text{if $n$ is even}
\end{cases}$

I am not totally sure that it is convergent or not , but it's rearrangement series convergent, but as it is a series with positive and negative terms , don't know what will be it's rearrangement series behaviour.

But if it is not convergent, is there any other examples of convergent alternating series with non monotonic terms $\{u_n\}$

Or the statement is true.

Comment: At the end of the first sentence, are you sure that it's $=0$? Instead of $\ne0$.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos sir,sorry , for the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that asserting that$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N):u_{n+1}\not< u_n$$is the same thing as asserting that$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N):u_{n+1}\geqslant u_n,\tag1$$which is not true for your sequence. If each $u_n$ is greater than $0$ and if $(1)$ holds, then you cannot possibly have $\lim_{n\to\infty}u_n=0$, and therefore you also cannot have $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^{n-1}u_n=0$. So, your series diverges.

Comment: Sir, $u_n \gt 0 $ , it is given before the statement in the definition of alternating series.

Comment: Also, sir $u_{n+1} \not\lt u_n $ mean also for a non monotonic terms together with monotonic increasing.

Comment: I have edited my answer. And $u_{n+1}\not< u_n$ means one and only one thing: that $u_{n+1}\geqslant u_n$.

Comment: I understood what you mean sir, but what if we omit the "$\forall n $" part from $u_{n+1}\lt u_n $, is then really the statement remaining true or not?

Comment: And also is my given example of series really convergent?

Comment: A better option would be to write that the sequence $(u_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is not monotonic decreasing, not even just when $n$ is large enough. Or then to write that$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N)(\exists m\in\Bbb N):m\geqslant n\wedge u_{m+1}\geqslant u_m.$$

Comment: Yes, if you meant that $(u_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is not monotonic decreasing, not even just when $n$ is large enough, then your example is fine.

Comment: thank you sir, for suggestions and answers.